# Ask users what menu they want while drupal is being installed

Tags: 7

I am working on installation profile. I wanted to give user choice to choose what menu items he wants like home, about us and another. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, using [`hook_install_tasks()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_install_tasks/7).

You can use this hook to create a form that is displayed to your users during the installation process; it can be a standard Drupal form and you can add as many items of content/menu links as you want in the submission function.

Bear in mind the hook and forms your implement will need to go in the .profile file, not the .install file, or they won't work.

Comment: Drupal wont accept creating of menu with out content.

Comment: Yep...so create some content (as my answer notes), then create the menu links :)

Comment: You mean to say to use some node_import module and import data and then create menu links?

Comment: No you can actually create a home page, about page etc. and assign them to a menu there and then. Have a look at the standard.install file in profiles/standard, it shows you what you need to do

Comment: I tried, but did not find anything for menu and content creation directly in installation profile